# Make Spotify URI links clickable system wide?

Tags: hyperlink, links, spotify, uri

So, is it possible to make Spotify URI links clickable like any hyperlink so that they just directly play that song in the client when the link is clicked ?

Comment: Have you tried to research (google) anything regarding your issue? If you did please provide the references.